# Diagonalize symmetric matrix through congruent transform

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that the definition of diagonalization is: for square matrix $A$, to find invertible matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ that $$A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$$

If $A$ is symmetric, then above decomposition is always possible: $$A=P\Lambda P^{-1}=P\Lambda P^T$$  where $P$ is also orthogonal. $\Lambda$ is unique up to permutation of its diagonal entries.

My question is: for a symmetric matrix $A$, whether it is possible to find irreversible matrix $Q$ and diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ such that $$A=Q\Sigma Q^T$$
holds? Note here $Q$ is not reversible and $\Sigma$ is different from above $\Lambda$ considering permutation.

Comment: I don't know what "reversible" means.

Comment: By "reversible" I mean invertible in "Note here $Q$ is not reversible". Stack exchange marks a red waved line under "invertible" so I want to use another one.

Comment: If $Q$ is not invertible, then neither is $A$, so your equation won't be possible for an invertible $A$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $Q$ is an arbitrary noninvertible matrix, and $\Sigma$ is an arbitrary diagonal (hence, symmetric) matrix, then your product will be symmetric, so at least for some symmetric $A$ it can be done.

Comment: Is there any condition for the existence of mentioned "diagonalization" for some symmetric matrices which have zero eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be symmetric and not invertible. Let $P$ be orthogonal and $D$ diagonal such that $A=PDP^t$. Then $D$ has at least one zero on its diagonal. Let $J$ be the matrix with zero everywhere $D$ has a zero, and $1$ everywhere $D$ has a nonzero entry. Then $J=J^t$, $JD=DJ=DJD=D$, $A=(PJ)D(JP)^t$, and $PJ$ is not invertible.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly. Let's say $D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, J=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$, then $JD=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \ne D$

Comment: $J$ has a zero everywhere $D$ has a zero, and a $1$ everywhere $D$ has a nonzero entry. Your "example" completely fails to meet this definition.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken about the definition of $J$. Whether can we find another decomposition in which the diagonal matrix is different from the one formed by eigenvalues (the set of diagonal entries is not equal to the set of eigenvalues)?

Comment: You could let $J$ have arbitrary nonzero entries instead of ones, and adjust $D$ accordingly.

Comment: This is a smart answer, thanks.

Comment: If it satisfactorily answers your question, you can "accept" it by clicking in the little check mark next to it.

Comment: Are you still here, @jizhou?